# Laravel 5.4 'join' Query

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5.4, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

```
public function scopeGetCompanyInfoWithBank($query, $comCode) 
{
    $query->select(
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(COM_NAME), '') AS COM_NAME"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(COM_ADD1), '') AS COM_ADD1"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(COM_ADD2), '') AS COM_ADD2"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(COM_ADD3), '') AS COM_ADD3"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(COM_ADD4), '') AS COM_ADD4"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(COM_BNKCODE), '') AS COM_BNKCODE"),
        DB::raw("CONCAT(rtrim(BANK_NAME), '') AS BANK_NAME") // NOT WORKING.
    )
    ->join("bank", function ($join) {
        $join->on('bank.BANK_CODE', "=", 'COM_BNKCODE');
    })
    ->where('COM_CODE', '=', $comCode)
    ->get();
}
```

- 2 tables: 'company' and 'bank'.
- 'COM_CODE': Primary Key of 'company'.
- 'BANK_CODE': Primary Key of 'bank'.
- 'COM_BNKCODE': Foreign Key of 'company' = 'BANK_CODE'.

**Issue:**
unable to get 'BANK_NAME' from above query.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean "Unable to get bank name" do you get in error? please post.

Answer (score -1):

hope this will help you

public function scopeGetCompanyInfoWithBank($query, $comCode) 
{
    $this->data['query'] = company::join('bank','BANK_CODE','=','company.COM_BNKCODE')
                           ->select('company.COM_NAME','company.COM_ADD1',
                            'company.COM_ADD2','company.COM_ADD3',
                            'company.COM_ADD4','company.COM_BNKCODE')
                           ->where('company.COM_CODE', '=', $comCode)
                           ->get();
}

Comment: ,This won't help me at all :( thanks for the effort :) I think, you don't understand my question at least :/ My Issue:
unable to get 'BANK_NAME' from above query.